# What is the Latex command for Z_n[i] in mathematics where i is iota complex number

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I'm new in this field and I make presentations on latex but I am stuck in this problem, What is the Latex command for `Z_n[i]` in mathematics where i is an iota complex number?

My approach is `$\mathbb{Z_n{[i]}}$` but this seems incorrect.
Does anyone suggest the correct command?

Comment: `\mathbb` should only be applied to Z not the whole expression, you are applying it to n and i which will produce nonsense as only capital letters are provided in moset mathbb fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, sir can u tell me what should I use for it?

Comment: your question isn't very clear but I assume you want `$\mathbb{Z}_{n}[i]$` or if you want iota and not i then `$\mathbb{Z}_{n}[\iota]$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot sir, this is working for my proplem.

Answer (score 7):

`\mathbb` should only be applied to Z not the whole expression, you are applying it to n and i which will produce nonsense as only capital letters are provided in most mathbb fonts

I assume you want `$\mathbb{Z}_{n}[i]$` or if you want iota and not i then `$\mathbb{Z}_{n}[\iota]$`